# How do I use arrow functions filtering a property by a list

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, arrow-functions

I have an array of objects and I am trying to remove several elements by a list of ids in another array.

Say I have

```
transactions = [{id:12, name:'trs1'}, {id:18, name:'trs18'}, {id:45, name:'trs145'}, {id:98, name:'trs19'}];

ids = [12, 98];
```

Then I want to end up with

```
transactions = [{id:18, name:'trs18'}, {id:45, name:'trs145'}];
```

I am trying to remove the elements from the transactions array that have the id specified in the ids array.

I am thinking of creating a sub array doing a filter and replacing the original array with this new sub array which does not contains the elements included in the ids array.

Something like

```
var subArray = transactions.filter(trans => trans.id != ids)
transactions = subArray;
```

But I am new to arrow functions and I don't know how to accomplish this. In the documentation I only see that they use == as the comparison operator. But I am looking for something that compares against a list of elements.

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check the `id` with [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

```js
var transactions = [{ id: 12, name: 'trs1' }, { id: 18, name: 'trs18' }, { id: 45, name: 'trs145' }, { id: 98, name: 'trs19' }],
    ids = [12, 98],
    subArray = transactions.filter(trans => ids.every(id => trans.id !== id));

console.log(subArray);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with [Array#includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check if the `ids` array doesn't contain an `id`:

```js
const transactions = [{id:12, name:'trs1'}, {id:18, name:'trs18'}, {id:45, name:'trs145'}, {id:98, name:'trs19'}];

const ids = [12, 98];

const result = transactions.filter(({ id }) => !ids.includes(id));

console.log(result);
```

Another options is to create a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) from the `ids` array, and check if the set doesn't [have](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has) the `id`:

```js
const transactions = [{id:12, name:'trs1'}, {id:18, name:'trs18'}, {id:45, name:'trs145'}, {id:98, name:'trs19'}];

const ids = [12, 98];
const idsSet = new Set([12, 98]);

const result = transactions.filter(({ id }) => !idsSet.has(id));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I like this solution and it works if I wanted the list of the elements that I want to remove... However, I ultimately want the list of the elements that are NOT in the ids array. Is there an exclude or similar? Something opposite to include. I couldn't find that in the documentation.

Comment: @jpavelw - you can use the `!` (not) operator to negate includes, and Set#has. See updated examples.